# Is possible to use a DKIM-Proxy to signing emails requested from another application?

Tags: postfix, smtp, dkim

I using an application to send emails, written in golang which use `net/smtp` as SMTP Libary, however that lib provide no support with DKIM signing, but using a `sendmail` command, for example, the DKIM is being signined.

I am Postifx as MTA and I read that it would be possible to use a dkim-proxy so that the email sent by the application comes out with the signature

Comment: Yes, that's normal operation of Postfix + OpenDKIM milter.

Comment: if i interpret the question, you have a working smtp and smtp proxy for dkim, which signs every email that goes out? why not using then localhost as smtp server and use your existing setup?

Comment: I don't want to use an external server to sign DKIM and do everything local, what I would like is to keep the application sending, but its SMTP library doesn't sign DKIM, and that's why I read that I should use a dkim-proxy, I I was seeing a configuration that happens on localhost but on different ports for signing and outputting signed emails